# Include rows and columns with zero hits in sklearn metrics confusion_matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I want to combine results from several confusion matrixes in a single matrix. My prediction and ground truth values can be 0, 1, 2.
I can add up values whenever all values are present. However the number of rows and columns changes when some values are not present at all. Hence, I cannot add such array to the resulting array. How to force confusion matrix include rows and columns with zero samples in them?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

combined_confusion_matrix = np.zeros((3,3))
gt1 = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2])
pred1 = np.array([2,1,2,0,1,2])
cm1 = confusion_matrix(gt1, pred1)  # [[1 0 1][0 2 0][0 0 2]]
combined_confusion_matrix +=  cm1
gt2 = np.array([0,0,2,2])
pred2 = np.array([0,2,2,2])
cm2 = confusion_matrix(gt2, pred2)  # Got [[1 1][0 2]], Desired [[1 0 1][0 0 0][0 0 2]]
combined_confusion_matrix += cm2  # Error due to different dimensions
```

Comment: Can you explain how combining `combined_confusion_matrix` with `cm2` ends up with your desired output. I mean that how do you add `[[1 1][0 2]]` with `[[1 0 1][0 2 0][0 0 2]]` and get `[[1 0 1][0 0 0][0 0 2]]`

Comment: Have you tried defining your own function to transform the confusion matrix?

Comment: It is sufficient to specify a list of labels and pass it to confusion_matrix as an argument. CM cannot guess which classes outcomes are possible, so it only shows a matrix for outcomes with non-empty rows and columns. CM extends the matrix to all labels if you provide the list of labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
my_bins = [0, 1, 2]
cm2 = confusion_matrix(gt2, pred2, labels=my_bins)
```